# How to run a Spring Boot Application in a real online website instead of localhost:8080

Tags: spring-boot

I've created an application with the spring boot framework.
Everything runs fine on the localhost:8080. 
Now I want to be able to run the application from my website. 
So people can log in to the app and use the application from anywhere over the internet. 
What should I do to manage this?

Comment: you can try AWS for free deployment upto certain hits,Google it out :- EC2 instance

Comment: You need to deploy it on cloud web servers such as AWS - EC2 you can find more information on https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Comment: Is it also possible to deploy the application and host it on a fully-fledged server of your own for example a server at your office?  And then people  run the web application via a domain name that points to the ip adress of your server.